# Mean-type series convergence if a sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Reading a paper i have found that they use the following proposition:

If  a convergent sequence $\{c_k\}$ with limit $c$, then
$$\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{k^2 c_k}{N^3} \rightarrow \frac{c}{3}.$$
It's similar to the well-known arithmetic mean convergence, i.e., under the same assumption we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^N  \frac{c_k}{N} \rightarrow c.$$

I've alredy tried to use a similar approach to arithmetic mean convergence
\begin{align*}
|\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{k^2 c_k}{N^3} -\frac{c}{3}|&\leq \frac{1}{3N^3} \sum_{k=1}^N |3k^2 c_k -cN^3|\\
&\leq \frac{1}{3N^3} \sum_{k=1}^N |3k^2 c_k -3k^2 c|+\frac{1}{3N^3} \sum_{k=1}^N |3k^2 c -cN^3|\\
&=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N | c_k - c|+c\sum_{k=1}^N (\frac{1}{3}-\frac{k^2}{N^3})
\end{align*}
So, the first term of the last inequality goes to zero, as $N\rightarrow \infty$, but the second term even doesn't converge. And i have the same problem using different "zeros" in the second step.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sum_{k=1}^N k^2=1+2^2+...+N^2=\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$, we have
$$
\frac c3 =\lim_{N\to\infty}
\sum_{k=1}^N {k^2c}{N^3}.
$$
Then along your original approach,
$$
\Big(\lim_{N\to\infty}
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{k^2c_k}{N^3}\Big)-\frac c3=\lim_{N\to\infty}
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{k^2c_k}{N^3}-\lim_{N\to\infty}
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{k^2c}{N^3}=\lim_{N\to\infty}
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{k^2(c_k-c)}{N^3}.
$$
The limit on the right is $0$ as you observed.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$
a_n := \sum_{k=1}^n k^2c_k
$
and $b_n := \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ (which defines an increasing sequence divergence to $\infty$). One can check that
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n} 
= \frac{(n+1)^2 c_{n+1}}{(n+1)^2} = c_{n+1} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} c
$$
so, by the [Stolz—Cèsaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_for_the_%E2%88%99/%E2%88%9E_case),
$$
\frac{a_n}{b_n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} c
$$
as well.
Now, note that
$$
\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{6n^3}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{n^3} c_k
$$
to conclude, as $\frac{6n^3}{n(n+1)(2n+1)} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 3$.